# NullPointerException in my BluetoothCommandService

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm creating a home automation android application with my arduino uno and HC-05 Bluetooth Module. Everything works fine already. It can scan, connect, on/off bluetooth, control the bulb on and off using buttons and switch control.

My biggest problem is that it stops and automatically end the app when the switch control is clicked while the application is not yet connected to my bluetooth module is . I've been trying so hard to fix the error but  still nothing happend. Thanks in advance to those who have ideas for this.

Here are what is being listed in the LogCat:

```
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.example.javac101.BluetoothCommandService.write(BluetoothCommandService.java:222)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.example.javac101.ControllerTab.sendData(ControllerTab.java:390)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.example.javac101.ControllerTab.onCheckedChanged(ControllerTab.java:271)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:126)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:666)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-02 00:02:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It might be not clear to understand so here are my codes in my BluetoothCommandService:

```
package com.example.javac101;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothCommandService {

    private final BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
    private final Handler bluetoothHandler;
    private static int connectionState;
    private ConnectThread connectThread;
    //private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    public static ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    private AcceptThread mainAcceptThread;

    public static final int stateNothing = 0; //doing nothing
    public static final int stateListen = 1; //listening for incoming connections
    public static final int stateConnecting = 2; //initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int stateConnected = 3;

    //constants that indicate command to computer
    public static final int exitCMD = -1;
    public static final int VOL_UP = 1;
    public static final int VOL_DOWN = 2;

    private static final boolean D = true;
    private static final String tagState = "BluetoothCommandService";


     private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final String name = "BluetoothCommand";
    private static final String BluetoothCommandService = null;

    public BluetoothCommandService(Context context, Handler handler) { // context == UI Activity Context && handler == send message back to the UI Activity
        BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        connectionState = stateNothing;
        bluetoothHandler = handler;
    }

    private  synchronized void setState(int state) { // state == current connection state; an integer
        if (D) Log.d(tagState, "setState() " + connectionState + " -> " + state);
        connectionState = state;

        bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerTab.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();       
    }

    public synchronized int getState() { //return the current connection state
        return connectionState;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(tagState, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (connectThread != null) 
        {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (connectedThread != null)
        {
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mainAcceptThread == null) 
        {
            mainAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mainAcceptThread.start();
        }

        setState(stateListen);
    }

    //device == the BluetoothDevice to connect
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(tagState, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (connectionState == stateConnecting) {
            if (connectThread != null)
            {
                connectThread.cancel(); 
                connectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (connectedThread != null) 
        {
            connectedThread.cancel(); 
            connectedThread = null;
        }

     // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
        {
            mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
            mainAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        connectThread.start();
        setState(stateConnecting);
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(tagState, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (connectThread != null) 
        {
            connectThread.cancel(); 
            connectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (connectedThread != null) 
        {
            connectedThread.cancel(); 
            connectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
        {
            mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
            mainAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        connectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerTab.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ControllerTab.DEVICENAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(stateConnected);
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(tagState, "stop");

        if (connectThread != null) 
        {
            connectThread.cancel(); 
            connectThread = null;
        }

        if (connectedThread != null) 
        {
            connectedThread.cancel(); 
            connectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
        {
            mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
            mainAcceptThread = null;
        }

        setState(stateNothing);
    }

    public static void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
            r = connectedThread;
        r.write(out);
    }

    public void write(int out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (connectionState != stateConnected) return;
            r = connectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(stateListen);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerTab.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ControllerTab.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
            setState(stateListen);
            // Send a failure message back to the Activity
            Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerTab.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(ControllerTab.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
            msg.setData(bundle);
            bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        public final BluetoothSocket connectThread_socket;
        public final BluetoothDevice connectThread_device;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            connectThread_device = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            //Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection w/ the given BT device
            //try {
                //tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);} //ready to start a secure outgoing connection to this remote device using SDP lookup of uuid

            //catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(tag, msg, tr)
                //Log.e(tagState, "create() failed", e);}

            //Added 12/28/13
            Method m;
            try {
                    m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                    tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } 


            connectThread_socket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(tagState, "BEGIN ConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                connectThread_socket.connect();}
            catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    connectThread_socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "Unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothCommandService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                connectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(connectThread_socket, connectThread_device); //ERROR: will still create "connected"
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectThread_socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }       
    }

    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        public final BluetoothSocket connectedThread_socket;
        public final InputStream connectedThread_inStream;
        public final OutputStream connectedThread_outStream;
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(tagState, "create ConnectedThread");
            connectedThread_socket = socket;

            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

         // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            connectedThread_inStream = tmpIn;
            connectedThread_outStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(tagState, "BEGIN ConnectedThread");
            //BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis, 8 * 128);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // WALA JUD KO KASABOT ANI MAN :D
                                            //buffer == the bytes to write
                                            //buffer store for the stream

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    int bytes = connectedThread_inStream.read(buffer);
                            //BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis, 8 * 128);
//                          int bytes = new BufferedInputStream(null, 8 * 128).read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerTab.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer) 
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost(); //ERROR: will still create "private void CONNECTIONLOST"
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void write(int out) {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(exitCMD);
                connectedThread_socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket acceptThread_ServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = BTAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, myUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            acceptThread_ServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(tagState, "BEGIN mainAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (connectionState != stateConnected) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = acceptThread_ServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                        switch (connectionState) {
                        case stateListen:
                        case stateConnecting:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case stateNothing:
                        case stateConnected:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(tagState, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(tagState, "END mainAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(tagState, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                acceptThread_ServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ControllerTab where line 390 is located:

```
    private void sendData(String message) throws IOException
{
byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
Log.d(tagStateCTRL, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");
BluetoothCommandService.write(msgBuffer);
}
```

Comment: `r.write(out);` r seems to be null in your write method

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
        r = connectedThread;
    r.write(out);
}
```

Your problem lies in the above code. `connectedThread` is `null`, you then assign this `null` into `r`, and call `.write(out)` on a `null` resulting in a **NPE**